# Reducing π to zero (again)

Tags: mathematics

You are given the first 20 digits of π: 31415926535897932384. In each move, you can select a **contiguous** group of 5 digits and increase/decrease them all by the same integer, provided that each resulting digit stays between 0 and 9 inclusive. For example you can increase the first 5 digits by 2, giving you **53637**926535897932384. However you cannot decrease the same 5 digits by 2 as that would result in negative digits. Can you bring every digit to 0?

---

**To allow new users to solve this puzzle and earn reputation points, I encourage all users whose reputation is 200 or more to not post an answer until 48 hours after this question is posted.  Thank you!**

---

<sub>This is a variant of the question [Reducing $\pi$ to zero](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/109378/reducing-pi-to-zero)    by [Dmitry Kamenetsky](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/62537/dmitry-kamenetsky).</sub>

Comment: Is there any practical usefulness in solving such a problem?

Comment: @webadventurer I enjoy puzzles.  I don’t care if they have any real world application.  I would characterize myself as a pure mathematician not an applied mathematician.  I do math because I enjoy its intrinsic beauty.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

At the time of writing, I am currently at 196 reputation, so I am just under the limit.

I believe that you cannot reduce the first 20 digits of $\pi$ to 0.

> We start by adding all the digits in the question together, to get the number $97$. This is our starting sum $S$.
>  We also notice that each time we increase a contiguous group of 5 digits by a number $k$, we increase $S$ by $5k$, where $k$ is some integer. (Reducing a group of 5 digits is the same as having a negative $k$).
>  
>  Therefore, if we are only able to increase or reduce $S$ by multiples of 5 at each step, the last digit of $S$ can only ever be $7$ or $2$. However, for $\pi$ to be reduced to 0, $S$ must equal $0$. Therefore, it is impossible to reduce $\pi$ to 0 by only increasing/decreasing groups of 5 digits.

Comment: Your answer is correct even if the 5 digits are not contiguous.

Comment: Yes, I was just following the wording of the question

Comment: It is common to use spoilers to give others a chance at completing it themselves. I believe you can add them with `>!` in front of your text.

Comment: @infinitezero I have now spoilered the explanation, do you think I should spoiler the answer as well?

Comment: I think it's good this way :)